# Get count of all instances before a certain date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------
RecID|name  |date
--------------------------------------
1    |John  | 05/09/2016 
2    |John  | 05/02/2016 
3    |Mary  | 05/09/2016 
4    |Mary  | 05/08/2016 
5    |Mary  | 03/02/2016
```

and I want to get the count for name for each instance in which that name has appeared on or before that date in the row. So I want the output to look like this:

```
--------------------------------------
RecID|name  |date        |count
--------------------------------------
1    |John  | 05/09/2016 | 2 
2    |John  | 05/02/2016 | 1 
3    |Mary  | 05/09/2016 | 3 
4    |Mary  | 05/08/2016 | 2 
5    |Mary  | 03/02/2016 | 1
```

Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `count` function with a window specification.

```
select t.*, count(*) over(partition by name order by date) as cnt
from tablename t
```

This will produce incorrect results if there are mutliple rows on a given date for a name. One way to avoid this is using a correlated sub-query.

```
select t.*, 
(select count(distinct t2.date) 
 from tablename t2 
 where t2.name=t.name and t2.date<=t.date) as cnt
from tablename t
```

Or use `row_number`.

```
select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by date) as cnt
from tablename t
```

Or use `dense_rank` if there can be multiple rows for the same name on a given date.

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over(partition by name order by date) as cnt
from tablename t
```

The easiest solution of all would be to use `dense_rank`.

Comment: @GurV .. all the 3 queries using count() over() , row_number and dense_rank would give the same result if there are no ties.

Comment: never used count() with `order by` before. Nice one. and tried dense too, all works. +1

Answer (score 1):

use

```
count(*) count
```

and

```
group by date
```

if your date is already a string (i.e. without hour/minute information)